# Accessing files on a what was a Synology NAS HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I have a HDD that was part of a Synology NAS (replaced as failing).

I have it connected by USB to my Ubuntu PC.

GParted sees the HDD and lists the partitions.

Files (explorer) does not see the HDD.

How can i access he HDD, Partitions and files.

Apparently Synology uses a BTRFS file system ?? is that the problem ?? .

I'm hopping that there is a simple way of doing this as most things to do with entering stuff in the Terminal is ???? to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but maybe I can help you with some experiences I did.
As the HDD was probably a RAID device you have to install some packages for RAID.

As root in a terminal session (`$ sudo -i`), you have to install following applications:

Update Ubuntu

```
apt update
```

Install the RAID applications:

```
apt install lvm2
apt install myadm
```

Test the HDD:

```
vgscan --mknodes
```

you will receive something as:

```
Found volume group "vg1000" using metadata type lvm2
```

Activate the HDD:

```
vgchange -ay
```

you will receive something as:

```
1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1000" now active
```

Make a display:

```
lvdisplay
```

you will see somthing as:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1000/lv
  LV Name                lv
  VG Name                vg1000
  LV UUID                I4OgWe-gTw1-ucJM-PB9w-Pa2X-UsvE-IyoHxX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                3,63 TiB
  Current LE             952682
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Now create a mountpoint:

```
mkdir /mnt/old_HDD
```

Mount the volume:

```
mount -o ro /dev/vg1000/lv /mnt/old_HDD
```

List the contents:

```
ls /mnt/old_HDD
```

You will see something as:

```
@appstore  @autoupdate  @cloudstation  @database  @download  @eaDir  homes  @iSCSI  music  photo  @S2S  @tmp  @USBCopy  video
```

I further installad today 2 new apps:

```
apt install dcfldd (copy disk=to=disk) and btrfs (install btrfs-progs)
```

If I have some news I will come back to you. I'm very new in Ubuntu (1 week, after over 40 years in Mainframe-System Engineering).

Hope this helps a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

launch Terminal

$ sudo apt-get install update
$ sudo apt-get install mdadm
$ sudo apt-get install lvm2
$ sudo mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay

The hard disk now is mounted

goto File to find the hard disk